# How to find the index of the 1st occurence of a condition ( > 0 in my case) in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

All in the title. I tried so many things I can't even count. My goal is to count how many 0 are before the 1st occurrence of a number which is > 0 in `numArr`, so I can work with that later in my code. I truly have no clue how to do this properly.

My code so far :

```js
function incrementString(strng) {
  // loop though the splitted array
  let newArr = strng.split('');
  let numArr = [];
  let lettersArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(newArr[i]) === false) {
      numArr.push(parseInt(newArr[i]));
    } else {
      lettersArr.push(newArr[i]);
    }
  }

  let newNbr = parseInt(numArr.join('')) + 1;
  let result = lettersArr.join('') + newNbr;
  console.log(numArr, result);
}

incrementString('foobar0100');
```

Comment: [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: This reminds me of [lolphp](https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1ofw7t/2d9/)

Comment: Based on the fact you named the function "incrementString", what is the end goal? Do you want to get `foobar0101`?

Comment: The title says *"How to find the index of the 1st occurrence of a condition ( > 0 in my case)*" but the body says *"My goal is to count how many 0 are before the 1st occurrence of a number which is > 0 in numArr"*

Comment: For your `incrementString('foobar9')`, would the expected result be `'foobar10'`? I could see that being problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert your string to an array of characters (you can use the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this) and then use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the first character that fulfils your condition:

```js
const text = 'foobar0100';
const index = [...text].findIndex((character) => Number(character) > 0);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Also an interesting note here is that `[...text].findIndex(Number)` is functionally equivalent due to the fact that `letter` is always a single character. But I wouldn't change it to that because this is more readable and clearly indicates its intent.

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a regular expression for finding the characters `'1'` ... `'9'`.

```js
function findNumber(string) {
    return Array.from(string).findIndex(s => /[1-9]/.test(s));
}

console.log(findNumber('foobar0100'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all browsers and has no weird syntax - assuming I understood your question correctly

```js
var incrementedString = 'foobar0100'.replace(/[1-9]/, function(num, pos, string) {
  return (++num);
});
console.log(incrementedString)
```